# Rails searching a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I have a Property and Customers model. Property `has_one :customer` and Customer `belongs_to :property`. Property has an address column of type string.

I am trying to allow users to search Customers by the address of the property it belongs to.

```
# customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: property

  def self.search(search, user)
    if search
      where('full_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").where(user: user)
    else
      where(user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

Doing this doesn't work:

```
  def self.search(search, user)
    if search
      where('full_name LIKE ? OR property.address LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%").where(user: user)
    else
      where(user: user)
    end
  end
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a "join."

```
  def self.search(search, user)
    if search
      joins(:property).where('properties.address LIKE ?', "%#{search}%").where(user: user)
    else
      where(user: user)
    end
  end
```

In SQL terminology this is called an "inner join."

Here is the [Rails Guide on joining tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).